# How to check for a product within a Shopify collection using Liquid?

Tags: arrays, collections, shopify, liquid

I have a products object:

`assign rel_products = collection.products`

How can I check for a specific product within this object? By `id` preferably. I'm doing this check so I can `continue` in a for loop:

```
{% if rel_products contains related_product.id %}
    {% continue %}
{% endif %}
```

This code above isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very familiar with liquid but the problem in your code snippet looks like you are assigning the collection to the variable rel_products, so you will have to loop through that and then check the id in each iteration. Possibly something like this?

```
{% for product in rel_products  %} 
    {% if product contains 'Id you want to check' %}
        {% continue %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be the solution you needed.

```
{% assign rel_products = collection.products %}

{% for product in rel_products %}
      {% if product.id == 12345789 %}   //123456789 is just an example
          <!-- Something you want to do -->
      {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```